# Enable DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to recompile my Linux Kernel 3.18 with DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER enabled, but editing the .config file is not working.

I have the dependencies enabled, but it still shows and not enabled.

Is there a way i can do this without editing the Kconfig file? Do i need to enable any special module for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some symbols are not allowed to be explicitly selected by the user, but instead they are meant to be selected by other symbols.

You can identify such symbols because they don't have a "prompt" next to the symbol type (bool, tristate). This is the case of CONFIG_KMS_DMA_HELPER:

```
config DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER
        bool
        select DRM_GEM_CMA_HELPER
        select DRM_KMS_FB_HELPER
        select FB_SYS_FILLRECT
        select FB_SYS_COPYAREA
        select FB_SYS_IMAGEBLIT
        help
          Choose this if you need the KMS CMA helper functions
```

In contrast, here's a symbol with a "prompt" text:

```
config KERNEL_GZIP
        bool "Gzip"
        depends on HAVE_KERNEL_GZIP
        help
          The old and tried gzip compression. It provides a good balance
          between compression ratio and decompression speed.
```

In other words, it's not possible to explicitly enable CONFIG_DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER. It's meant to be *selected* by other symbols (DRM drivers such as rcar-du, shmobile, tilcdc, and others).

Thus, if you are writing a driver that needs the functions provided when such option is enabled, you can simply *select* the option as the mentioned DRM drivers do.